# making divs with auto margins in parent div with variable height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    /***main***/

    <div style="top:0">
        /*****Content1****/
    </div>

    <div>
        /*****Content2****/
    </div>

    <div>
        /*****Content2****/
    </div>

    <div style="bottom:0">
        /*****Content4****/
    </div>

</div>
```

I want content1 always at top and content4 always at bottom, also want content2 and content3 adjust top and bottom margin equally so that it look even, I am unable to do this, as parent div is of variable height and all other divs are of fixed height.

I think this will help you to understand what I want
http://www.spoiledagent.com/ads/Help.jpg

Please help,

Comment: Do you have a style sheet or are you starting from nothing?

Comment: You van visit the website
http://www.spoiledagent.com/
I have used this at the right side, and You can see what mess it is creating

Comment: Try adding "position:absolute;" to BOTH the div containing Content1 and Content4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4XaQ/

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content1">/*****Content1****/</div>
    <div id="content2">/*****Content2****/</div>
    <div id="content3">/*****Content3****/</div>
    <div id="bottom">/*****Content4****/</div>
</div>

#main{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    background: red;
}

#content1{
    height: 80px;
    background: gray;
}

#content2{
    width:480px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
}

#content3{
    width:480px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
    background: brown;
}

#bottom{
    height: 50px;
    clear:both;
    background: blue;;
}
```

Comment: content1, content2, content3 and content4 are one below another and the main has variable height on different pages but all are having width of 250px

Comment: I think this will help you to understand what I want
http://www.spoiledagent.com/ads/Help.jpg

Comment: In this case, you have to use % instead px. But is the same principle.

Comment: Show what you're trying in jsfiddle

Comment: Here I have given height to the parent div but this is variable and we cannot specify it
http://jsfiddle.net/Q4XaQ/6/
I want the equal top and bottom margin between the other div so that it look even.